# How to set pointer to something if it's null and I can't deference it?

Tags: c++

```
static jclass *classExample;

getClassAndCache(env, classExample, "[Lcom/my_package/MyClass;");

static void getClassAndCache(JNIEnv *env, jclass *cacheHere, std::string className)
{
    *cacheHere = env->FindClass(className.c_str());
    assert(cacheHere != NULL);
}
```

The problem is that I get a NULL deference pointer, because, obviously, I'm trying to deference `classExample` to assign it to the result of `env->FindClass`. I tried doing

```
cacheHere = &(env->FindClass(className.c_str()));
```

but it won't work because I can't take the address of an rvalue.

So what should I do?

Comment: This is the typical "how to modify function arguments" but with a pointer.

Comment: I might be off-base since I don't have experience with JNI but why are you not using `static jclass classExample;`?

Comment: you dont want to "set the pointer to something" but you want to change the value of what the pointer points to. however, when the pointer points nowhere, you cant